# Backbone: A list of views inside a view

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Let me show what I need first so you can understand my problem.
I have a contact view like:

```
ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("Name: <%= name %>
                          E-mail: <%= email %>
                          Phones
                          <%= label1 %> - <%= number1 %>
                          <%= label2 %> - <%= number2 %>"),
    render: function() {
       var contact = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
       this.$el.html(contact);
    }
});
```

So far so good, the problem is that the phones part is a list, my model holds an array of phones, and I need to put it dynamically in that template.

What I thought was to create another model and view Phone and PhoneView just for this.
And then in the ContactView I would create a method render_phones, like:

```
render_phones: function() {
    var phones = this.model.get('phones');
    var phones_str = "";
    for (var i in phones) {
        var phone = new Phone(phones[i]);
        var phoneView = new PhoneView({model: phone});
        phones_str += phoneView.render();
    }
    return phones_str;
}
```

I changed the ContactView template to this:

```
template: _.template("Name: <%= name %>
                      E-mail: <%= email %>
                      Phones
                      <%= phones %>"),
```

**But how to make my render method get the phone list rendered and put inside the template?**

I couldn't find a pattern to deal with situations like this. And the code is starting to look not so good.

ps: This is just an example, there are several other parts of my application that I need this, a view that need to generate subviews with content in a list.

Comment: I mean, the render method already have: this.template(this.model.toJSON());
I would have to make the phones string be a part of the model, so it could render in the template showed. But that would be a very ugly and (I think) not correct way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using underscore.js to render your templates, underscore.js provides a way for [rendering a collection](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) within a template (look at the second example). for example

```
template: _.template("Name: <%= name %>
                          E-mail: <%= email %>
                          Phones
                <% _.each(phones, function (phone) { %>
                 <%= label %> - <%= number %>
                <% }); %>"),
```

You can also render an individual view for each model and in the same render model modify the `el` to render it there, but unless you need the view (for example the content will change or you're listening to events) it probably doesn't pay to do it that way. Here's an example of how you could accomplish that

```
render: function () {
  this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());
  _.each(this.model.get('phones'), function(phone) {
    this.$el.find('.phoneArea').append(new phoneView({model: phone}).render().el));
  },this);
  return this;
}
```

Also if you were to go this route then note that it would probably pay to cache the views, but again if all you need is to render the content then it would probably pay to just keep the phone numbers as an array and render it within the template.

Comment: Thank you very much man! I used the first example as I found it to be the shorter and elegant way, nice!

Comment: Glad to help, as I mentioned unless you have a reason to use the second approach you are probably better off with the first.