# Backbone/Marionette - How to define the correct Region

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, region

I've run into an issue which I can't find any documentation on, so I'm unsure if it's possible to do.

I have a backbone application which is running fine and it builds me a list of "wells" based on incoming iq packets to a pubsub node (lets call this backboneApp1).

At the end of the template of this backbone well is the following:

```
<div class='row' id='row-participants-<%= chatid %>' style='display: none'>
</div>
```

This is a div which I wish to append a list of participants to (this doesn't exist at the time the document is loaded and the ***MyApp.start*** is called).

This list of participants is being built using backbone marionette based on another set of incoming iq packets which lists the participants for a particular chat id (lets call this backboneApp2).

So when defining the region for backbone to use, it's done in two parts.

The first, is where you add the region and define the unique name and the DOM:

```
MyApp.addRegions({
    participantsContainer... : "#row-participants-..."
})
```

The second is where you tell backbone to show the view:

```
MyApp.participantsContainer.show(aParticipantsView);
```

So in my above scenario, I need to create the region dynamically (where do I do this? can this be done in the ***initialize*** for backboneApp1 because I'm passing the chatid into each model in my collection of wells? Or maybe in the pubsub handler function, before I send the data to backbone?).

Then I need to tell backboneApp2 to ***show()*** in the correct region based on the chatid, which is where I'm stuck (chatid is also passed, each model in the collection has a participantName value and a chatid value associated with it).
Where would I put the second part of defining a region if I'm planning to pass a parameter into it?

Please ask if any further explanation is required.

Thank you.

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

EDIT: This seems to be the solution, but I'm unsure how to do it without underscore [Backbone: A list of views inside a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209030/backbone-a-list-of-views-inside-a-view)

My code:

CREATING PARTICIPANTS ARRAY

```
var participants = [];
$(iq).find('participants').each(function() {
    var participantsNodes = this.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < participantsNodes.length; i++) {
        var participantAttr = participantsNodes[i].attributes
        var participant = participantAttr[0].nodeValue;
            participants.push({"name": participant, "chatid": chatid});
    }
});

model.set({
    participants : participants,
    chatid : chatid
    ...
});
```

ITEMVIEW

```
GroupChatView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : "#template-groupchat",
    tagName : 'div',
    className : 'alert alert-custom',

    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.prop("id", this.model.get("chatid"));
    },

    ...
```

GROUPCHAT TEMPLATE

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-groupchat">

    <a id='close-<%= chatid %>' class='close hide' data-dismiss='alert' href='#'>
        &times;
    </a>
    ...
    <div class='row' id='row-participants-<%= chatid %>' style='display: none'>
<!-- CUSTOM CODE SHOULD BE HERE? -->
    </div>

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Hi gerf, the code is above for how you normally tell backbone where to add the collection. So where it says `MyApp.participantsContainer.show(aParticipantsView);`, the `participantsContainer` is the region to add to. Is there a way to have this region defined by the id of the models? so it only appends to the model in question

Comment: Maybe I am thinking about this wrong? Here is the use case: I use backbone to build a collection of divs each representing one group chat. On change of the participants value passed into the model (where the model is a group chat) I need to update the participant view inside the group chat model view to reflect the new participant list. Does this make sense?

Comment: Regions are probably not what you want to be using for this purpose. If you're creating rows, you'll either want to use a CollectionView or CompositeView.

Comment: Looked around a bit more and found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209030/backbone-a-list-of-views-inside-a-view which is pretty much what I am trying to do, render a list inside a model... I have no idea how to do this though for myself as I have never used underscore. Added the relevant code to main post.

Comment: As this is no longer valid to the original title, I have modes this to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515580/rendering-an-array-as-a-list-within-a-backbone-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using underscore to render the collection in the template.